# Swift - remove all delivered notifications on all devices

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've made a simple app, which is receiving push notifications from a service called OneSignal. This service just pushes notifications to devices without any user tracking, etc. so the user receives the notification on all devices, the app is installed.

I was wondering if it's possible to clear all notifications in the notification center on all devices in swift, without any server side modifications, like sending a badge=0 push to all other devices? My goal is, that when the user taps the notification / opens the App on his iPhone, the notifications are cleared on his iPad or other iCloud-linked device too.

This works unfortunately just locally and not on all devices of the same Apple ID:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

Comment: Hi dude, this is not posible without server side modifications you can not access the application on another device without consult any service and update badge.

Comment: Hey @AlejandroViquez thanks for your fast reply. I already had the feeling, that this won't be possible but now I've confidence. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome dude!